# find if tinter object overlaps with ball in canvas python

Tags: python, tkinter

If I have a ball in tkinter with radius 20 at coordinates x,y. What's the best method to find out if another object is touching it or partially overlapping it. I tried equating the coordinates of the two objects however that would only happen in very specific cases. Is there a away I can build a list that contains all the coordinates the ball occupies using its center coordinates and its radius?

Thank you

Comment: the canvas has a `find_overlapping` method. Have you tried using it?

Answer (score 0):

The circle's circumference consists of all the points that are exactly 20 units from the center. Therefore, if the distance from an edge of your object to the circle's center is less than 20, it will be inside the circle. If it's exactly 20, it will be touching the circle.